# Make a custom type post featured

Tags: wordpress

I made a custom post type with CPT UI. On the listing page (wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=promotions), I don't see the little star button to make the post featured as with default posts.

How do I add that button ?

Coming from Drupal and struggling. Help me out :)

Comment: The closest built-in functionality to featured posts is making posts sticky, but the behavior is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option in WordPress to make a post features this way. You can make a post featured by creating a category featured Like(Featured Promotion in your case) and then add your promotions to that category.